# how to make 100% buttons with fixed pixel space

Tags: css

how to make fluid layout css with buttons(width 100%) ?

UI look like this....

```
---------------- width 100%--------------------------------------------------------
btn1(100%) | space(5pixel fixed)  | btn2(100%) | space(5pixel fixed)  | btn(100%)
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------


 <ul class="wrapper">
   <li><a href="#" class="btn"></a></li>
   <li><a href="#" class="btn"></a></li>
   <li><a href="#" class="btn"></a></li>
 </ul>
```

Comment: find the updated solution below - @user1833620

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[Working jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Pw8eq/)**

If you have only **three** buttons in your navigation, this CSS will help:

```
.wrapper {
    width: 100%;
}

.wrapper li {
    position: relative;
    background: orange;
    width: 33%;
    float: left;
}

.wrapper li + li { width: 34%; }
.wrapper li + li + li { width: 33%; }

.wrapper li a {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
}

.wrapper li + li:before {
    position: absolute;
    content: '';
    width: 5px;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background: #fff;
}
```

And here is the output:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

From the UI that you have provided as a display of how it should look, here is a [Working Solution](http://jsfiddle.net/9Mmne/2/) for the same.

**The HTML:**

```
 <ul class="wrapper">
   <li><a href="#" class="btn">abc</a></li>
   <li><a href="#" class="btn">def</a></li>
   <li><a href="#" class="btn">ghi</a></li>
 </ul>
```

**The CSS:**

```
body{margin:0; padding:0;}
.wrapper{display:table; width:100%; margin:0; padding:0;}
.wrapper li{display:table-cell; list-style-type:none; background:#cccccc; border-right:5px solid #ffffff;}
.wrapper li:last-child{border:none;}
.wrapper li a{display:block; text-align:center;}
```

When the parent width is `100%`, the child elements can accommodate widths accordingly if wrapper is having a `display:table;` and child having `display:table-cell;`.

**EDIT**

For the extra 5px space that is required, just added a border-right without distorting the layout on the slider or zoom stretch. As I suggest not to put any width for the `li` and let them accommodate itself to occupy the parent width. Hope this helps now.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Same solutions, it's just that you missed the 5px width spacing  ;)

Comment: Yeah, I was posting my answer and saw a new answer and saw yours. - @Mr.Alien

Comment: An alternative to the right borders is to use `border-spacing`, although it does create a border all the way around each cell, which might be a limitation: `.wrapper{border-spacing:5px;}`

Comment: True @ralph.m It does create a border all the way and that is the limitation.

Answer (score 1):

Try this (**[Demo](http://jsbin.com/ubozux/1/edit)**):

```
ul {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;

    /* flexbox setup */
    display: -webkit-box;
    -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;

    display: -moz-box;
    -moz-box-orient: horizontal;

    display: box;
    box-orient: horizontal;
}

li {
    -webkit-box-flex: 1;
    -moz-box-flex: 1;
    box-flex: 1;  

    margin-right: 5px;
    padding: 0;
    background: #eee;
    text-align: center;
}

li:last-child {
    margin-right: 0;
}
```